# A package for formatting Linux terminal excerpts?

Tags: packages, formatting, syntax

I know about `minted` and `listings`, but either of those are intended for formatting of programming languages excerpts.  Is there a package that would do the same for Linux terminal excerpts?

Such as:

```
peter@kbpet:~$ echo $(uname -i)
x86_64
```

The minimal solution would be to automatically embolden the `peter@kbpet:` to every line and indent the leading line of each block.

The other major convenience sought is math symbols like `$` and `_` should be automatically interpreted as escaped.

Comment: What kind of extra formatting are you looking for? My terminal output is just fixed-width text. I know some programs can output colours but this is not based on syntactic information so highlighting it will be difficult (e.g., `ls` colouring certain file types or permissions).

Comment: @Pieter: The minimal solution would be to embolden the `$bob@system:` prelude to every terminal line and indent the leading line of each block.

Comment: Both packages support `bash` as language. So you should this give a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you think about this suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{Bash}
{language=bash,
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
morekeywords={peter@kbpet},
alsoletter={:~$},
morekeywords=[2]{peter@kbpet:},
keywordstyle=[2]{\color{red}},
literate={\$}{{\textcolor{red}{\$}}}1 
         {:}{{\textcolor{red}{:}}}1
         {~}{{\textcolor{red}{\textasciitilde}}}1,
}



\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=Bash]
peter@kbpet:~$ echo $(uname -i)
x86_64

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On the right track.  Can the `peter@kbpet:` be emboldened, and can output be a different colour, indented, or otherwise set apart from the user's input?

Comment: @ptrcao: Sorry but I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @ptrcao: I edited my post. What do you think?

Comment: Yep, getting real close.  The last request is that the terminal output, in this case `x86_64` be indented.  The difficulty is that there is no intelligent way to program a macro that will distinguish output lines from commands.  It seems it has to be manually done at this stage, which makes it impractical as all the possible commands and outputs will be prolific and inexhaustible.  If anyone is smart enough to conceive of a macro that could distinguish terminal output from commands intelligently by getting feedback from the the OS itself, that would make my day.  For now, answer accepted.

Comment: This can be done by 'write18'

Comment: How so?  I have read documentation on write18 and am still unsure how it can help us here?