# Macro for formatting computer code?

Tags: macros

I need to create documents containing lots of small bits of R code, which are *not* to be sent to R via knitr. Ideally, it should work very much like code is formatted here at Stackexchange. It should be set in ttfamily and not break across lines. I'm not sure that a gray background is necessary. I'd prefer not to use `\begin{environment}` and `\end{environment}`, because that's cumbersome when the code is just a couple words.

It seems like the trickiest part might be that some special characters should loose their specialness. Specifically, "$" and "_", which are commonly used in R code shouldn't have to be escaped.

There is a solution to a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29453/a-package-for-formatting-linux-terminal-excerpts), but that's taking the \begin{}\end{} approach, so it won't work here.

Something like `\code{my code}` would work better. I have the beginnings of a macro with this:

```
\newcommand{\nbcode}[1]{\mbox{\texttt{#1}}}
```

It'd be great if the solution to this is a package I haven't heard of.

Comment: listings package does syntax highlighting and has a command form for inline code fragments

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Print programs with its proper syntax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25425/5764); [How to format an inline source code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19004/5764)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method offered by LaTeX is the `\verb` macro and the `verbatim` environment.
So for example you can write `\verb|print($hello)|` and obtain `print($hello)`.
Note that instead of regular brackets, `\verb`'s argument is delimited by whichever character you put right after it. This allows you to avoid escaping the delimiters by just choosing a delimiter that does not conflict with the contents.

You should also have a look at the standard packages for this kind of things:

- `verbatim`
- `fancyvrb`
- `listings`
- `minted`

These offer many different ways to customise the appearance of the code by offering boxes, colors, highlighting etc.