# Typset shell code with sensible terminal highlighting in LaTeX

Tags: beamer, listings, minted, code

I'm familiar with typesetting script code in my documents, however, I have been unable to obtain nice highlighting for shell code (e.g. similar to that afforded to me by my `gnome-terminal`).

Basically this is what I would like to get:

[image]

The best I can do with `listings` is the following code:

```
\definecolor{tlg}{gray}{0.9}
\lstset{frame=tb,
    backgroundcolor = \color{tlg},
    language=bash,
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},
    numbers=none,
    rulecolor=\color{tlg},
    backgroundcolor=\color{tlg},
    fillcolor=\color{tlg},
    rulesepcolor=\color{tlg},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=3
}


\begin{lstlisting}
chymera@quiethost ~/myfolder $ ls -lh
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 mytext_final.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 mytext_final_version2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:57 mytext.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 mytext_version2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 mytext_version3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 mytext_version4.txt

\end{lstlisting}
```

which produces:

[image]

And the best I can do with `minted` is the following code:

```
\begin{minted}{bash}
chymera@quiethost ~/myfolder $ ls -lh
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 mytext_final.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 mytext_final_version2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:57 mytext.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 mytext_version2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 mytext_version3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 mytext_version4.txt
\end{minted}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29453/a-package-for-formatting-linux-terminal-excerpts could help

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307129/terminal-screenshot-generator/307130

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using *fancyvrb* package

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\textcolor{green}{chymera@quiethost} \textcolor{blue!50}{~/myfolder $} ls -lh
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 \textcolor{green!50!black}{mytext_final.txt}
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 \textcolor{green!50!black}{mytext_final_version2.txt}
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:57 \textcolor{green!50!black}{mytext.txt}
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 \textcolor{green!50!black}{mytext_version2.txt}
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 \textcolor{green!50!black}{mytext_version3.txt}
-rw-r--r-- 1 chymera chymera 0  1. Mai 23:58 \textcolor{green!50!black}{mytext_version4.txt}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

the result is

[image: code highlighted]